# Emacs .dir-locals.el - setting key bindings

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

I'm not sure this is possible, but I'd like to setup some project specific key bindings by using `.dir-locals.el`

Of course `.dir-locals.el` has to contain a special list of settings, so I can't do:

```
(global-set-key [24 down] 'move-text-down)
```

Is there any way I can inject a lambda to run arbitrary code or some other way to set key bindings in `.dir-locals.el`?

Comment: Your question is too general.
What's the language, number of projects and number of different
behaviors for each project? Give some examples.

Comment: @abo-abo ... sorry, but you simply don't understand the question, there's nothing general about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `eval` pseudo-variable enables you to specify arbitrary elisp for evaluation with your local variables.

e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7340962/324105

See [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables) for more details.

Note that this is not a particularly useful mechanism for setting key bindings, as every buffer using the keymap in question will be affected. You would probably be better off using the dir-local config to enable a minor mode with the specific keymap for that project. Alternatively, you might adapt [this approach to file-local bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21493693/324105) (but a minor mode would be nicer).

That being said...

A fairly minimal form is `((nil . ((eval . (progn BODY)))))` with `BODY` being the expressions to be evaluated. Of course if `BODY` is only a single expression, you do not need `progn`.

The following therefore displays a message when you visit any file (under the directory in question):

```
((nil . ((eval . (message "hello")))))
```

The car of each list in the dir-locals form is generally a major mode symbol, or `nil` (as in the above example) in which case the settings apply in *any* major mode.

The car can also specify a sub-directory string, in which case the cdr is another dir-locals form with settings applicable to that sub-dir.

Comment: so, essentially .. a .dir-locals.el containing : `((eval . (progn BODY)))` ? (I'll give it a try)

Comment: At minimum the format would be `((nil . ((eval . (progn BODY)))))` -- the car of each list in the form is a (major mode) symbol, or `nil` (as in this example) indicating settings which apply in *any* major mode. (The car can also specify a (sub-directory) string, and then settings applicable to that sub-dir).

Comment: Thanks @phils, the emacs request to mark the `.dir-locals.el` as safe is displayed, however the code inside the `progn` body doesn't appear to execute. I added a `(message "hello")` to check in *Messages* and isn't displayed. Tried with a lambda instead, also didn't execute. Any more ideas?

Comment: `((nil . ((eval . (progn (message "hello"))))))` works just fine for me (as does a `global-set-key`).

Comment: Works fine now, I trashed the broken one, so not sure what I screwed up, but definitely a chair to keyboard interface issue. I'll paste in your working example into your answer for future reference.